# Apply style using document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply a grey background color to a div element inside a page.

Thats the one highlighted below:

[image]

I am able to apply the background color with the below code in the page onload:

```
var topBar = document.querySelector("td.top-bar div.top-bar");
alert(topBar);
topBar.style.backgroundColor="#808080";
```

However, there is a background property that is undoing what I applied:

[image]

How can I remove the highlighted "background" property?

I tried topBar.style.background = "".

But it doesnt work.

Comment: so set the background, not a background color

Comment: wow awesome!! @epascarello awesome

Comment: Please show all code as text, not as pictures of text. You can select code from Styles tab in Developer Tools easily enough, and right-click a node in the Elements panel and select Copy > Copy outerHTML to get the specific HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing other css property. To make it work you have to overwrite background, not background-color. The easiest way is just to do this:

```
var topBar = document.querySelector("td.top-bar div.top-bar");
topBar.style.background="#808080";
```

It should works